# EOS coin transaction with python

Tags: python, eos

I'm trying to use the EOS coin for payment of my website.
But for few days, it was hard to find about python api or modules to do.
c++, and JS could do but, I prefer to use python~!

Can I get some help?

Comment: For your website? Are you trying to run Python as a backend server? As a CGI script? As an independent endpoint invoked from JS? Python doesn't run in the browser like JS, so you won't be doing client-side scripting with it.

Comment: Oh~! I will use it for my Linux server side.
And I'm using django so.I want to know if there is a python option for the EOS coin~!

Comment: Did you check this? https://cryptotoken-converter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/payments/payments.coin_handlers.EOS.html